# how to install ubuntu for android?

Tags: installation, android

I want to add ubuntu alongside with my android OS, how can I do so, I can't find a ubuntu package for the android device. I have a lenovo P770 android device with me.

Answer (score 1):

Visit Ubuntu Official Website ([click here](http://ubuntu.com)) and download the Ubuntu Touch for Android.

Note- In Order to Install Ubuntu Touch for Android, you need to have Ubuntu Installed onto your PC to Root the device with Ubuntu Touch OS.

1. Before you go any further, check if your device satisfies the laid down minimum requirements for Ubuntu Touch.

   - Should have a min of 1Gb RAM
   - Device must have dual core processor or greater.